# jQuery focus() on Bootstrap input field not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want a search input field to automatically get focus on page load. So I tried the following approach:

```
(function () {
    $('#searchbox').focus();
})
```

This however does nothing at all. I thought it might conflict with some other code I have, so I did a simple test at a Bootstrap example page http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html. In the Chrome console, I typed `$('input:first').focus();` and this gave me `<input class="span2" type="text" placeholder="Email">` as return value, but it didn't focus on the e-mail field too.

What am I doing wrong to simply focus on a certain input field when a page loaded?

Comment: You can't focus from the console because it currently has focus (imagine trying to focus while another tab is active - it won't work).

If you do `setTimeout(function(){$('input').eq(0).focus();}, 1000);` and quickly click back to focus the page again it will work. Can you post a link to the page you're having issues with or set up a fiddle?

Comment: $(function(){$('#searchbox').focus();});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to wait until page has loaded. Try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {$('#searchbox').focus(); });
```

Comment: I thought if I placed the JS at the bottom, the DOM would be ready by then. This fixed the issue.

Comment: @EsTeGe You had just to add '$' in your code to get it work: $(function(){$('#searchbox').focus();});

Answer (score 4):

Your initial code should work just fine, but you didn't add the second pair of brackets to call your anonymous function. If it's at the bottom of the page, the relevant part of the DOM will be ready by then, making the jQuery domready unnecessary.

`;(function () {
    $('#searchbox').focus();
})();`

Should work just fine